# How do I partition my data to ensure equality among the resulting groups?

Tags: matlab

I have a number of subjects that each have a single score. I would like to assign these subjects to a number of (roughly) equally-sized groups such that the resulting groups all have a (roughly) equal average score. What is the smartest way to go about this, conceptually? I will be implementing the code in MATLAB.

My first solution is to sort the subjects on their scores. I then assign the subjects to groups by alternating groups, much as a card dealer deals cards to a number of players. This works pretty well, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

```
n = 200; %number of subjects
k = 5; %number of desired groups
subjects = linspace(1,n,n)'; %subject ids
scores = randi(100,n,1); %scores
data = [subjects,scores];
data = sortrows(data,-2);
group_subjects = cell(1,k);
group_scores = cell(1,k);
x=1;
for i = 1:n
   if x>k, x=1; end
   group_subjects{x} = [group_subjects{x},data(i,1)];
   group_scores{x} = [group_scores{x},data(i,2)];
   x = x+1;
end
avg_scores = cellfun(@mean,group_scores)
```

My ultimate goal is to output the subjects by group as in `group_subjects`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest keeping what you have so far as a "starting" partition.

Once you have such a starting partition, I would suggest taking the partitions with the largest and smallest averages, and exchanging members between them by some rule in order to bring the averages closer to the global average. If you repeat that in a loop until you can't find an appropriate pair of members to switch in the current partitions with the largest and smallest partitions (that is, selecting the partitions with the largest and smallest after each swap), you should be left with at least a local optimum.

So how do you select the appropriate pair of numbers to swap? Well, you're looking for numbers such that they minimise how far their difference is from the required change in sums to make their averages equal, with the added restriction that they should not cause the average to overcompensate and end up causing them to be further apart.

```
while 1
 sm_idx=find(avg_scores==min(avg_scores),1); %Choose a set with the smallest average
 lg_idx=find(avg_scores==max(avg_scores),1); %Same with largest average
 pcorr=round((avg_scores(lg_idx)-avg_scores(sm_idx))*...
  (length(group_scores{lg_idx})*length(group_scores{sm_idx}))/...
  (length(group_scores{lg_idx})+length(group_scores{sm_idx}))); %Calculate perfect correction
 M = group_scores{lg_idx}'*ones(size(group_scores{sm_idx}))-...
  ones(size(group_scores{lg_idx}'))*group_scores{sm_idx}; %note: assumes group_scores are row vectors
 Midx=find(abs(M-pcorr)==min(abs(M-pcorr)(:)),1);
 if (abs(M(Midx)-pcorr)>=pcorr)
     break;
 end
 [l_c_idx,s_c_idx] = ind2sub(size(M),Midx);
 temp=group_scores{lg_idx}(l_c_idx);
 group_scores{lg_idx}(l_c_idx)=group_scores{sm_idx}(s_c_idx);
 group_scores{sm_idx}(s_c_idx)=temp;
 temp=group_subjects{lg_idx}(l_c_idx);
 group_subjects{lg_idx}(l_c_idx)=group_subjects{sm_idx}(s_c_idx);
 group_subjects{sm_idx}(s_c_idx)=temp;
 avg_scores(lg_idx)=avg_scores(lg_idx)-M(Midx)/length(group_scores{lg_idx});
 avg_scores(sm_idx)=avg_scores(sm_idx)+M(Midx)/length(group_scores{sm_idx});
end
```

Testing as a follow-up to your code, I'm getting results like this:

Before my loop:

```
avg_scores =
 54.000
 53.525
 53.050
 52.500
 51.925
```

After my loop:

```
avg_scores =
 53.000
 53.000
 53.000
 53.000
 53.000
```

As you can see, it sometimes gets a perfect result.

One minor curiosity with the code is that it will always prefer the first match producing the result, as written. For a little more randomness to make finding the optimal solution a little more likely, you can replace

```
Midx=find(abs(M-pcorr)==min(abs(M-pcorr)(:)),1);
```

with

```
Midx_options=find(abs(M-pcorr)==min(abs(M-pcorr)(:)));
Midx=Midx(randi(length(Midx)));
```

This will make it choose a best-switch at random from the set of switches that are optimal.